# Avoid sourcing scripts multiple times

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, terminal, bashrc

At the moment, when I open a terminal on my Mac, it automatically calls:

`source ~/.bash_profile`.

What bemuses me, however, is that my shell does not seem to inherit any of the content from `~/.bashrc` or `~/.profile`. But that might be typical.

I have a number of scripts to inherit using `source` or `.`; if I put those calls in `~/.bash_profile`, it can take some time to load a new shell window, sometimes 3 or 4 seconds, and that gets old. I imagine that there is some way to source those scripts just once and have my `~/.bash_profile` file inherit it somehow.

Note that calling source ~/.bashrc or source ~/.profile from my ~/.bash_profile is not what I want to do, and is also probably a bad idea. It's not what I want to do because it doesn't solve the problem of a slow load for each new shell.

I added some echo statements; every time I open a new bash terminal window, this is logged:

```
starting to load /etc/profile
finished loading /etc/profile
starting to load bash_profile
finished loading bash_profile
```

that makes sense, but what is disheartening - do I really need to load these every time a new shell is opened? Why can't it do some fancy inheritance so that we don't have to reload everything every time?

I created a video demo'ing the problem.  I have 4 terminal applications I use regularly:

```
terminal.app                  # misbehaves
iterm2                        # misbehaves
webstorm terminal emulator    # misbehaves
vscode terminal emulator      # behaves!
```

VSCode actually behaves in the way I would desire. I am guessing that it does this by loading ~/.bash_profile in a parent shell, and only doing that once, when vscode boots up. All of the terminal windows in the app, are then subshells of that one parent shell.

**Hopefully this video makes the issue clear:**
https://www.useloom.com/share/4e62f0cb24434c4a83b8bd32844b596a

This is a legit issue - most terminal applications do this whole thing wrong, however, quite miraculously, it appears that VSCode from Microsoft actually does this whole thing the right way, see this issue:

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-31390

Comment: I don't understand why a terminal session is not just a subshell of a parent shell which has already inherited from /etc/profile or ~/.profile or whatever

Comment: There is no problem sourcing `.bashrc` from `.bash_profile` and it is quite common in fact.  Also related:  http://www.joshstaiger.org/archives/2005/07/bash_profile_vs.html | Additionally please edit your question with additional thoughts/details instead of commenting.

Comment: Yeah sourcing one file from another is not the answer here - that doesn't speed anything up - and one time I did that, I got an infinite loop when logging in, and I will never try that again :(

Comment: What I could do to avoid an infinite loop is have .bashrc/.bash_profile/.profile source a 4th file, but again that doesn't speed up loading a new terminal session

Comment: To do things only once one may use a guarding if-statement in the style of ```if [[ $BASH_SUBSHELL -eq 0 ]] ; then ....
        
fi```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This morning I moved a bunch of personal information out of my `bash_profile` and `bashrc` and added them to a new file I call `privaterc`.

In my `privaterc` file I set this variable:

```
PRIVATERC_RUN=yes
```

Now in my `bash_profile` I have added this line:

```
[[ $PRIVATERC_RUN != yes && -f ~/.privaterc ]] && source ~/.privaterc
```

This will cause `privaterc` to only be sourced if it hasn't previously been sourced in this shell.

---

Also as for the profile weirdness you are seeing, the article I linked in the comment states the following about mac:

> **Mac OS X — an exception**
>
> An exception to the terminal window guidelines is Mac OS X’s Terminal.app, which runs a login shell by default for each new terminal window, calling .bash_profile instead of .bashrc. Other GUI terminal emulators may do the same, but most tend not to.

Comment: that might work, I will try it

Comment: you think like me :) I also use "yes" instead of true/false

Comment: yeah this doesn't work as I was hoping. Every time I open a new terminal window, it will resource the .privaterc file. That makes sense because when you call `export` it won't change the parent shell. So what we need is a way so that an original parent shell is what's called when we first login, and then any terminal will already be a subshell of that parent shell..

Comment: do you follow what I am saying? any other ideas? I have always found info on this stuff to be a little wishy washy, but there must be some way to inherit stuff in a bash shell, instead of having to re-source stuff every time.

Answer (score 4):

I wonder it would be better to write a cliche in the sourced side, not sourcing side. (like C header files)

```
[[ "${_NAME_OF_THIS_LIBSCRIPT:-""}" == "yes" ]] && return 0
_NAME_OF_THIS_LIBSCRIPT=yes
```

With this, you do not need to repeat the same boiler plate every time you source a script file, which should contain something meant to be shared across multiple places.
Or am I missing something?
To be really honest, I am not a bash programming master, so I really would like to have insights from others.

Comment: This is not the best written bash, but the concept is valid!  This is exactly what I was thinking, and it baffled me why others where using some crazy controls on the source loading side!

Comment: my idea exactly (although also a bash newbie). and it seems to work fine.. :)

Answer (score 1):

Put a unique variable in the rc file - with a length of 1 or more bytes - then check if it has a length greater than 0 before sourcing bash_profile.

`if [ ! X”” = X”$uniq_var” ] ; then . ~/.bash_profile ; fi`

I just set bash as the login shell on MacOS, and didn’t have this problem. Perhaps they changed something again.

Comment: How do you set bash as the login shell on MacOS?

Comment: @AlexanderMills In settings. There are numerous tabs, you’ll find it.

Comment: yeah see: https://superuser.com/questions/362372/how-to-change-the-login-shell-on-mac-os-x-from-bash-to-zsh

Comment: @AlexanderMills I really liked Terminal.app, but I remember switching to iTerm2 after it got an overhaul - it was much more useful (tabswitching with CMD-{1,2,3,4,..} etc. 99% customizable. Try it if you can’t make Terminal.app behave.

Comment: Yeah I use iterm2 most of the time. I also use the built-in terminal for Webstorm and VSCode even more. I need to get them all to behave.

Comment: The good thing - all the terminals on my machine behave the same way.  They source /etc/profile and ~/.bash_profile when they load.

Comment: @AlexanderMills What happens if you rename those files? Bootup doesn’t usually pull anything from /etc/profile

Answer (score 1):

This is my version of test, based on Hiroshi_U's answer.

I want to test a function in `mylib.sh` with `$ source mylib.sh;sysLog Hey`, the function will not be up-to-date if I have changed something afterwards and try to get the newer result out of it. I have to unset the `_NAME_OF_THIS_LIBSCRIPT` to make it new. Since `$ echo $0` produces something like `-sh` and `-bash`, so I test for `-` to determine whether it run in a script file or under the shell.

mylib.sh

```
#!/bin/sh

MY_BASE=$0
[[ "${_NAME_OF_THIS_LIBSCRIPT:-""}" == "yes" ]] && return 0
[[ "${MY_BASE:0:1}" != "-" ]] && _NAME_OF_THIS_LIBSCRIPT=yes

function sysLOG() {
    echo $1 $_NAME_OF_THIS_LIBSCRIPT
}
```

test.sh

```
#!/bin/sh

source /tmp/mylib.sh
sysLOG 1
source /tmp/mylib.sh
sysLOG 2
source /tmp/mylib.sh
sysLOG 3
```

```
$ test.sh;echo $_NAME_OF_THIS_LIBSCRIPT
1 yes
2 yes
3 yes
```

```
$ source mylib.sh;sysLog Hey;echo $_NAME_OF_THIS_LIBSCRIPT
Hey! yes
```

Without `[[ "${MY_BASE:0:1}" != "-" ]] &&`

```
$ source mylib.sh;sysLog Hey;echo $_NAME_OF_THIS_LIBSCRIPT
Hey! yes
yes
```

Comment: Why ``MY_BASE=$(echo $0``)?  ``MY_BASE=$0`` is better.

Comment: What if `mylib.sh` is sourced inside other scripts that are supposed to be sourced, and which source other scripts? IINM, when you source a script from your shell, `$0` remains the name of the shell (`-bash`), so inside `mylib.sh` might be sourced multiple times.

Comment: @aviro Let me see, what you were saying is similar to `source test.sh;sysLOG Hi!`, right? As long as the rest part of `mylib.sh` contains functions only, I think, being sourced multiple times will not cause troubles. Since the goal of `$MY_BASE` is making debug  easier for `mylib.sh`.

Comment: Right, but the question was how to **avoid** sourcing multiple times. :) You could use `${#BASH_SOURCE[@]}` to check if the command is being sourced. For instance: `[[ "${MY_BASE:0:1}" != "-" || ${#BASH_SOURCE[@]} -gt 1 ]]` (this means that its source level is greater than 1, which means it's been sourced by another file being source).

Comment: @aviro Thank you for the tips, I didn't know I could do that. Unfortunately `sh` doesn't have `$BASH_SOURCE`, it gives out errors. I will dig more about it. If I can come out more suitable solutions I will edit my answer.